# Analysis of pgpdump output

Tags: cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle, openpgp

I have used `pgpdump` on an encrypted file (via BouncyCastle) to get more information about it and found several lines about partial start, partial continue and partial end.
So I was wondering what exactly this was describing. Is it some sort of fragmentation of plain text?

Furthermore what does the bit count stand for after the RSA algorithm? In this case it's 1022 bits, but I've seen files with 1023 and 1024bits.

[image: Dump Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial body lengths are pretty well explained by [this tumblr post](http://mrmekon.tumblr.com/post/12808217363).  OpenPGP messages are composed of packets of a given length.  Sometimes for large outputs (or in the case of packets from GnuPG, short messages), there will be partial body lengths that specify that another header will show up that tell the reader to continue reading From the post:

> A *partial body length* tells the parser: “I know there are at least N more bytes in this packet.  After N more bytes, there will be another header to tell if how many more bytes to read.”  The idea being, I guess, that you can encrypt a stream of data as it comes in without having to know when it ends.  Maybe you are PGP encrypting a speech, or some off-the-air TV.  I don’t know.  It can be infinite length — you can just keep throwing more partial body length headers in there, each one can handle up to a gigabyte in length.  Every gigabyte it informs the parser: “yeah, there’s more coming!”

So in the case of your screenshot, pgpdump reads 8192 bytes, then encounters another header that says to read another 2048 bytes.  after that 2k bytes, it hits another header for 1037 bytes, so on and so forth until the last continue header.  489 bytes after that is the end of the message

The 1022 bits, is the length of the public modulus.  It is always going to be close to 1024 (if you have a 1024-bit key) but it can end up being slightly shorter than that given the initial selection of the RSA parameters.  They are still called "1024-bit keys" though, even though they are slightly shorter than that.

Comment: Please don't just link to a tumblr post with the answer. Instead, incorporate a shortened version of the answer here and link to the tumblr post for reference. Links can break.

Comment: good point, I've been burned by tumblrs suddenly disappearing in the past.  I've added a bunch of summary/explaination taken from the link, and I'll try to keep that in mind in the future